# Update long running workflow in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, deployment

I have a question concerning how to manage installation of new versions of workflow features, in case when there are already running instances. It seems on my development machine that after installing new package all running workflows are automatically stopped. It is not a problem now, but how this is going to be handled after deploying to production? Stopping everything after update will surely be problematic.

[EDIT]

I see year ago someone had similar problem, no one knew the solution. Maybe this time it's a bit better?

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83905/sharepoint-2013-workflow-versioning

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: nope, just keep deploying through VS each time...

Answer (score 2):

The instruction how to update an existing workflow if it’s necessary to make changes to the workflow, but all running workflows must keep going:

1. Add ***ReplaceContent="TRUE"*** to Elements.xml files of workflow and workflow activities.
2. Create a wsp package with updated workflow/workflow activities.
3. Update the solution using the **Update-SPSolution** cmdlet.
4. Force enable the workflow and workflow activity features using the
   **Enable-SPFeature –force** cmdlet.

Look at my [question and answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163786/update-sharepoint-2013-workflow-with-custom-activities/164207#164207) for details.

Comment: I've merged the two questions into one (and up-voted your answer)