# Update Sharepoint 2013 Workflow with custom activities

Tags: 2013, workflow, custom, workflow-activity, update

I want to update my workflow 2013 with custom activities keeping running workflows going. Now I can do it only with a workflow without activities:

I've added **ReplaceContent="TRUE"** to the workflow's *Elements.xml* to File tag, so it looks like this `<File Url="Workflow.xaml" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="UpdateTestWorkflow\Workflow.xaml" DoGUIDFixUp="TRUE" ReplaceContent="TRUE">`. I make a wsp package, update it with *Sharepoint 2013 Management Shell* using **Update-SPSolution** and reactivate **workflow feature**.

In this way all running workflows keep going with the old version but when I start a new workflow it's running with the new version.

The problem starts when I add custom activities to my workflow. I can still update the workflow without any problems but when I try to reactivate the *activities feature* all my running workflows automatically terminate with the error:

> RequestorId: 68ee4e3e-62ff-8552-0000-000000000000. Details:
>   System.Activities.Statements.WorkflowTerminatedException: An activity
>   referenced by the associated workflow has been deprecated.

Does anybody know how to update sharepoint workflow custom activities keeping running workflows going?

Comment: If you deploy a new workflow to a new list does it work using your custom activity does it work?

Comment: I deploy my workflow as a list workflow and then add a list association manually. After wsp package update I can add a new list  and create a new assotiation for it, but my custom activities still will be old untill I reactivate the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an answer here - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a3acdbb0-079a-4c14-97f8-72d0af64eff8/updating-sp2013-workflow-custom-activities?forum=sharepointdevelopment

So, the instruction how to update an existing workflow if it’s necessary to make changes to the workflow, but all running workflows must keep going:

1. Add ***ReplaceContent="TRUE"*** to Elements.xml files of workflow and workflow activities.
2. Create a wsp package with updated workflow/workflow activities.
3. Update the solution using the **Update-SPSolution** cmdlet.
4. Force enable the workflow and workflow activity features using the
   **Enable-SPFeature –force** cmdlet.